# Bing web search api key not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bing-api

I am working on the Image Search Abstraction Layer FreeCodeCamp project and I got an API key for Bing Web Search API and I have installed node-bing-api npm module and added the key like this:

```
const Bing = require('node-bing-api')({accKey: "Key Here"});
```

and then I made a GET Request function to test if the API works or not, here is the function:

```js
app.get('/search/imagesearch/:searchTerm:offset?', (req, res, next) => {
    var searchTerm = req.params.searchTerm;
    var offset = req.params.offset;
    // Search With API
    Bing.images(searchTerm, {
        count: 10,
        offset: offset
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

and it returns me this:

```
{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription." }
```

I have tried both of the API keys which it has given to me, I am still getting same error message, 
Can anyone suggest what can be the problem?

Comment: make sure that you are trying to access same subscription which API key you have.

Comment: I did, I checked like 5 times if its the same key.

Comment: Web search and Image search can have different access keys. Are these free access keys or paid from Azure portal? If these are paid, which Tier these keys belong to? Image search will only work for S1, S3, S7, and S8.

Comment: @Ronak its the free keys, and i have not clue what tier it is XD how can i check?

Comment: You can check whether your free key is still good and applicable to image search API from here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/?api=bing-web-search-api. If you are using v7 endpoint, key should be applicable to both web and image. If you are not using, v7 keys, you can get the free keys from above link. That will require change in your endpoint - basically v5 should be v7.