# Bing Web Search API key not working

Tags: node.js, api, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to use Bing Web Search API using node-bing-api and am having the same error as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414372/bing-web-search-api-key-not-working-for-some-reason/) while making a nearly identical API call. The answers to that question have not been useful in my case. Other answers to this question are more than a year old and outdated.

I have this [service subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8xcg.png) (S3 pricing tier) and have tried the associated keys. Each keeps returning the 401 error. I have also tried using [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/?api=bing-web-search-api) to access the Web Search API, but the keys given there also return the 401 error.

At this point I have no idea why this is happening, nor how to fix it. Any help would surely contribute to my regained sanity.

Comment: Please edit your question to share code and error details (I mean, without your actual keys).

Comment: Pls share the API URL that you are trying to use.

Comment: It looks like the node-bing-api defaults to [v5](https://github.com/goferito/node-bing-api/blob/master/lib/bing.js#L24).  You can override the rootUri through an [options object](https://github.com/goferito/node-bing-api/blob/master/lib/bing.js#L13).

Comment: You can use this instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/quickstarts/nodejs.

Comment: thanks y'all. i created a fork of node-bing-api called [bingsearch7-api](https://github.com/f1ux1uxday/bingsearch7-api) in case anyone else would find that useful,